# como mostrar um aviso na tela quando o jogador perde o jogo? feito em javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function novoElemento(tagName, className) {
    const elem = document.createElement(tagName)
    elem.className = className
    return elem
    
}

function Barreira(reversa = false) {
    this.elemento = novoElemento('div', 'barreira')
    const borda = novoElemento('div', 'borda')
    const corpo = novoElemento('div', 'corpo')
    this.elemento.appendChild(reversa ? corpo : borda)
    this.elemento.appendChild(reversa ? borda : corpo) 

    this.setAltura = altura => corpo.style.height = `${altura}px`
}

function parDeBarreiras(altura, abertura, x) {
    this.elemento = novoElemento('div', 'par-de-barreiras')
    this.superior = new Barreira(true)
    this.inferior = new Barreira(false)

    this.elemento.appendChild(this.superior.elemento)
    this.elemento.appendChild(this.inferior.elemento)

    this.sortearAbertura = () => {
        const alturaSuperior = Math.random() * (altura - abertura)
        const alturaInferior = altura - abertura - alturaSuperior
        this.superior.setAltura(alturaSuperior)
        this.inferior.setAltura(alturaInferior)
    }

    this.getX = () => parseInt(this.elemento.style.left.split('px')[0])
    this.setX = x => this.elemento.style.left = `${x}px`
    this.getLargura = () => this.elemento.clientWidth

    this.sortearAbertura()
    this.setX(x)
    
}



function Barreiras(altura, largura, abertura, espaco, notificaPonto) {
    this.pares = [
        new parDeBarreiras(altura, abertura, largura),
        new parDeBarreiras(altura, abertura, largura + espaco),
        new parDeBarreiras(altura, abertura, largura + espaco * 2),
        new parDeBarreiras(altura, abertura, largura + espaco * 3)

    ]
    const deslocamento = 3
    this.animar = () => {
        this.pares.forEach(par => {
            par.setX(par.getX() - deslocamento)

            // quando a barreira sair da area do jogo
            if(par.getX() < -par.getLargura()){
                par.setX(par.getX() + espaco * this.pares.length)
                par.sortearAbertura()

            }
            const meio = largura / 2
            const cruzouOMeio = par.getX() + deslocamento >= meio
            && par.getX() < meio
            if(cruzouOMeio) notificaPonto()
        })
    }
}
// setando o passaro
function Passaro(alturaJogo) {
    let voando = false

    this.elemento = novoElemento('img', 'passaro')
    this.elemento.src = 'imgs/passaro.png'
    // posicao do passaro  e movimento
    this.getY = () => parseInt(this.elemento.style.bottom.split('px')[0])
    this.setY = y => this.elemento.style.bottom = `${y}px`
    window.onkeydown = e => voando = true
    window.onkeyup = e => voando = false

    this.animar = () => {
        const novoY = this.getY() + (voando ?  8 : -5)
        const alturaMaxima = alturaJogo - this.elemento.clientHeight
        //condiçao da altura do passaro
        if(novoY <= 0) {
            this.setY(0)
        } else if (novoY >= alturaMaxima) {
            this.setY(alturaMaxima)

        } else {
            this.setY(novoY)
        }
    }

    this.setY(alturaJogo / 2)
    
}
//fazendo a pontuaçao
function Progresso() {
    this.elemento = novoElemento('span', 'progresso')
    this.atualizarPontos = pontos => {
        this.elemento.innerHTML = pontos
    }
    this.atualizarPontos(0)
    
}




function estaoSobrepostos(elementoA, elementoB) {
    const a = elementoA.getBoundingClientRect()
    const b = elementoB.getBoundingClientRect()

    const horizontal = a.left + a.width >= b.left
     && b.left + b.width >= a.left

    const vertical = a.top + a.height >= b.top
      && b.top + b.height >= a.top
   return horizontal && vertical
    
}



function colidiu(passaro, barreiras) {
    let colidiu = false
    barreiras.pares.forEach(parDeBarreiras => {
        if (!colidiu) {
            const superior = parDeBarreiras.superior.elemento
            const inferior = parDeBarreiras.inferior.elemento
            colidiu = estaoSobrepostos(passaro.elemento, superior)
            || estaoSobrepostos(passaro.elemento, inferior)
            
        }
    })
    return colidiu
}


function FlappyBird() {
    let pontos = 0

    const areaDoJogo = document.querySelector('[wm-flappy]')
    const altura = areaDoJogo.clientHeight
    const largura = areaDoJogo.clientWidth

    const progresso = new Progresso()
    const barreiras = new Barreiras(altura, largura, 200, 400,
        () => progresso.atualizarPontos(++pontos))
    const passaro = new Passaro(altura)

    areaDoJogo.appendChild(progresso.elemento)
    areaDoJogo.appendChild(passaro.elemento)
    barreiras.pares.forEach(par => areaDoJogo.appendChild(par.elemento))

    this.start = () => {
        // loop do jogo
        const temporizador = setInterval(() => {
            barreiras.animar()
            passaro.animar()

            if (colidiu(passaro, barreiras,)) {
                clearInterval(temporizador)
            }
        }, 20)
    }
}

new FlappyBird().start()
```

Answer (score -3):

Recomendo deixar mais explicito oque você deseja fazer, maaas... você pode simplesmente na função colidir validar, caso não caia no early return que criou crie um alert citando que o user perdeu, pode também abrir um modal com bootstrap e jquery function abreModal() {
$("#myModal").modal({
show: true
});
}
setTimeout(abreModal, 1000); por exemplo. não sei se é isso oque quer fazer.